# Using a NavigationLink to go back to the previous screen without losing the data entered

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a view called Score4SelectPlayers where I enter data using textfields & pickers.

I then use a NavigationLink to go to a view called Hole1Score4View as below

```
NavigationLink(
                    destination: Hole1Score4View(scoreManager: scoreManager, course: course), tag: "Hole1", selection: $selection) { Text("Start Round") }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
```

On the second view I have hidden the NavigationBar and Back button and used a NavigationLink to go back to the previous view as I want a "clean" view with no NavigationBar.

```
NavigationLink(
                destination: Score4SelectPlayers(course: course), tag: "Players", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
            
            ZStack {
            
                    Button("") {
                        self.selection = "Players"
                        
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(ButtonNavigate())
                
                    Text("<< Prev")
            }
```

The issue I have is that when I go back to the first view using the NavigationLink the data I entered on it has disappeared & I have to enter it again.

If I have a NavigationBar including Back button (which I don't) when I go back the data I entered is still there and only needs to be amended as required which is the behaviour I want to replicate.

Is it possible in SwiftUI to use a NavigationLink to go back and still retain the original entered data on the first view?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going back to the first view, you're making a whole new one and pushing it onto the stack.

Make the navigation link using the initializer that has an `isActive` binding. Pass this binding to the pushed view. Set it to false when you want to go back.

You'll need to update `Hole1ScoreView` to have a property for the binding, and `Score4SelectPlayers` to hold a `@State` bool to store if the navigation link is active or not.